# c# drop down selected text

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm trying get text of the selected drop down item

My drop down list is filled of db data

```
ad.Fill(dt);
drop1.DataSource = dt;
drop1.DataTextField = "zodys";
drop1.DataValueField = "zodys";
drop1.DataBind();
```

for example: `word1, word2, word3, ...` 
All this is working fine, but when I try get text of the selected item I always get same text (text of the 1 item)

```
txtZip.Text = drop1.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can almost guarantee your problem is that you're defining the above within `Page_Load()`?  You need to only do this if you're not posting back, like so:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   ad.Fill(dt);
   drop1.DataSource = dt;
   drop1.DataTextField = "zodys";
   drop1.DataValueField = "zodys";
   drop1.DataBind();
}
```

This ensures that the value is not being reset each time prior to checking the SelectedItem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're databinding the dropdown also on postbacks in page_load. You should check for `IsPostBack`.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    ad.Fill(dt);
    drop1.DataSource = dt;
    drop1.DataTextField = "zodys";
    drop1.DataValueField = "zodys";
    drop1.DataBind();
}
```